# Irregular behavior of Django template tagss datetime.minute and datetime.hours

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates, datetime-format

So I have an object mydate
If I use the following tag :

{{mydate}}
It gives me the datetime according to my timezone, but if I use

{{mydate.hours}}  or {{mydate.minute}}

it gives the hours and minute according to UTC.

Am I missing out on something ??

Comment: how is the field defined in your model?

Comment: its a datetime field
`models.DateTimeField`

Answer (score 0):

You must use django [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

so you format date as you need, for example

```
{{ my_date|date:"D d M Y" }}
```